# Appcelerator - successful build but no archive in Xcode Organizer

Tags: xcode, appcelerator, archive

I have built some apps using Appcelerator/Xcode before.
Recently I got a new computer onto which I transferred all files from old computer.

I have Xcode 7.3
Running Appcelerator Studio with sdk 5.0.3 GA

Developing on iPhone hasn´t been a problem. App installs nicely.

Now I need to get the distribution to AppStore to work.
After build on Appcelerator, I get the message that packaging was successful and that archive is visible in Organizer,
hower it isn't.

All my old apps are visible in Organizer but not the new one.
I have tried several times.

Provisioning profiles and all seems to be in order.
Also, I can see that the folder with the app exists in
/developer/xcode/archives
along with all other ones.

Any ideas on where I should start investigate why the app is not visible in Organizer?

Thanks in advance
/Tove

Answer (score 0):

If your app folder is visible in archives, then you should check the app  version correctly, because all versions of an app resides in same folder and you can see the different versions and their dates created in Xcode Organizer.

See below image of Xcode -> Window -> Organizer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering Pranshant.
I now tried to open one of the archives (developer/xcode/archives...) that I created yesterday, by right cllicking and choosing "open with Xcode".

It didn't open. instead I got the message "cannot open archive, it is unreadable or corrupt".
I also tried the same on one of the archives that do show up in organizer, and that file opened up fine.

So something is wrong with the file. Any ideas what?
It has worked fine to build, and the dev version of the app is ok.

Comment: I do not know why you are opening the archives through Finder when there is already a smooth way to access it. As I answered you, use this path:  Xcode -> Window -> Organizer : to open the app for submitting to App Store or to validating or to exporting the build as .ipa. You can then refer my screenshot in answer above.

Comment: By Xcode -> Window -> Organizer, I meant to open the Xcode program and go to its menu bar to Window option and then Organizer.

Nevertheless, I have changed the screenshot in my answer to more descriptive one.

Comment: Thanks so much for getting back, Prashant.
I have used the Organizer all the time, and usually apps end up there automatically. Now I can't get them in there in any way I try.

Comment: It happens when your Privacy settings does not allow Appcelerator Studio to access your system. Make sure that Appcelerator Studio has check mark under Privacy tab in ***System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy*** (Select ***Accessibility*** in left-pane).

Even if it does not help, then there is no harm or issue by opening Organizer yourself :)

Comment: Hi again
Yep that checkmark is already there.
I think there is something wrong with the package/archive.
Any ideas what it can be?

Comment: I will try it some other time and will post here as an answer. Till then you can manually open the Organizer window

Comment: HI and thanks for trying to help,
however opening the Organizer is no problem.

Any idea why the archive seems corrupt and doesnt open in Xcode? Everything during dev worked fine and it worked fine to deploy on iPhone.

Comment: No idea other than the versioning issues. May be it's the Xcode itself causing the issues as once I was uploading an app to store and Xcode was showing some errors in my .ipa file but there were no errors at all, so I used Application Loader and it got uploaded on store and became ready for sale.

Answer (score 0):

In case it will help someone else:

This was an Appcelerator project that had worked nicely to build several times. Probably due to updates, I now found that having a specific info.plist file did not work.
I deleted it and all worked again.